# How do I ask my manager at summer internship (2 months), if they are looking to hire this year?

Tags: job-offer, recruitment, internship, mentoring

I have not been in contact after the internship, i.e. 4 months. I did not keep in touch, as I am kind of private person. But asking now, I don’t want to look selfish.. Also, if I do ask, whom should I approach ? There are 3 options

1. My direct mentor - I had maximum interaction with him, Mid-level manager
2. My Team lead - some interaction, Senior manager
3. Centre Director - Senior most person, knew me sufficiently well during internship, will initiate recruitment for the centre

The company had floated a form about 1 month after the internship, asking for feedback as well as if I'd like to work there, and I'd said yes.

One of my college seniors works there; he says there is little scope of a job offer to any intern. But my fellow students at college are recommending me to talk to senior managers at the company. Thanks for the help

Comment: How do I ask is also an issue, if any of you can indicate how best to ask - email / call; how to structure it etc. Any pointer to existing resources would also be helpful

Comment: I am not an intern as on date. Internship was over 4 months back

Comment: @DSR The answers will still be the same - contact your supervisor and say you would be interested in applying for a full-time position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach your past direct supervisor. He/she probably knows if there are any current openings and can recommend your candidacy to HR department. It can make your application process easier.